# What is the process when widgets use keys in their URL's query string? Is it safe?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I noticed whenever you're adding a script for a widget they give you something like:

```
<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=32324234-324324-32424234"> </script>
```

With the key= query being what differentiates your widget to others and for authentication

I'm just wondering what is the process with this, how is offering a key with a query tag safe when someone can just copy that code onto their website? Isn't it the same as essentially showing a password to everyone who visits the site

Is there something that happens behind the scenes like the key is matched with the URL? And if the url and key doesnt match it is not authorised?

Thank you so much, just trying to learn the process

Comment: Is `https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js` on your server?

Comment: @FZs no this example is from zendesk, the snippet.js is not hosted on my server

Comment: the key is primarily for identifying the user/client, the script itself suppose to contain logic checking whether the current domain matches the user/client's white-listed domains

Comment: and as you can test, changing/deleting the key gets the same script content